# Java Jframe looping getText and getInt in checkboxes

Tags: java, checkbox

Can someone help me for lopping this code?

```
 if(box1.isSelected()){ N = box1.getText();
    P = Float.valueOf(price1.getText());
    S = Integer.parseInt(spin1.getValue().toString());
    PT = S*P;
    selected();
 }
```

I have a total of 60 checkboxes. I use JFrame and every box has the variable name of box1 to box60. I just want to minimize my code.

Comment: if(box1.isSelected()){
N = box1.getText();
P = Float.valueOf(price1.getText());
S = Integer.parseInt(spin1.getValue().toString());}

Comment: that is the code sorry im new here

Comment: Use an array to store the text fields and reference by index, alternatively, if there is a one to one relationship between the checkbox and textField, use a Map